# Rewrite a differential equation formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently reading Elementary Differential Equations and I don't quite understand how they rewrote this Differential equation. I know that it is a very simple answer, but for some reason I can't see it. The formula is 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}p = 0.5p - 450 
$$

and it is rewritten too
$$
\frac{d}{dt}p = p - \frac{900}{2}
$$

I can tell the multiplied the equation by $2$, but how did they or why did they divide by $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the first equation was written as
$\frac{dp}{dt}=0.5p-450$ and the second equation was meant to be written as $\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{p-900}{2}$?

Comment: Hello Joel. Thanks for your answer. I actually think it was rewritten purposely, because they used the next equation to do the chain rule on (dp/dt)/p-900 = 1/2. Let me know if I am wrong, but this is how I think they got the answer, but I could be wrong. I think they multiplied 2 on both sides. So, we would have (2)(dp/dt) = p - 900 and then divided the 2 to the other side? Answer would be dp/dt = p - 900/2

Comment: Yes.  The two expressions are the same.  $0.5p-450=\frac{p}{2}-\frac{900}{2}=\frac{p-900}{2}$.